# JavaScript & jQuery: Calling inner functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in JavaScript and jQuery with an integrated ajax request.
Question: Why is it possible to call the inner function `success1()` but it is not possible to call `this.success2()` ? Any solution proposals for this problem?

```
function myfuntion() {
    this.url = "www.example.com/ajax.php";
    var success1 = function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS1");
    }
    this.success2 = function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS2");
    }
    this.send = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: this.url,
            dataType: "html"
        }).done(function (data) {
            success1(data);
            this.success2(data);
        });
    }
}
var test = new myfunction().send();
```

Comment: Because inside the callback, `this` refers to another object.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword for an excellent explanation of JavaScript's 'this'

Answer (score 1):

As other commented, the context of `this` inside the send function is changed, so that's why your `success2` function is not calling. You should save `myFunction` context in a variable and use that variable to refer `this` context.

Try this:

```
function myfuntion() {
    var self = this;                // taking the current context in a variable.

    self.url = "www.example.com/ajax.php";
    var success1 = function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS1");
    }
    self.success2 = function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS2");
    }
    self.send = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: self.url,
            dataType: "html"
        }).done(function (data) {
            success1(data);
            self.success2(data);
        });
    }
}
```